# Postgred pg_notify/listen only working if channel name is lower case

Tags: node.js, postgresql, notify, pg-notify

I've read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-notify.html and the channel name is just described as an 'identifier'.

I'm using NodeJS and pg https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg to access postgres.

If I use a lower case word in both, e.g. `pg_notify('foo', ...` and `LISTEN foo` it works.  I've tested all combinations:

```
pg_notify  LISTEN  outcome
lower      lower   works
lower      upper   works
upper      lower   fails
upper      upper   fails
```

Is this a bug, or is it a logical result of being an 'identifier'?  (If so, should this  be documented on pg_notify page?)

Comment: `pg_notify` is a function - so it is an identifier and works despite the case (unless you double quote it of course). what page you want it fixed at?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Sorry, I haven't understood all of your comment.  It *is* quoted, while I'm testing this issue, and is a string from a table when live.  I would like a note on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-notify.html sating that if you use an upper-case identifier string, then it will not work.

Comment: please share your not working code. ```t=# select PG_NOTIFY('a','a');
 pg_notify
-----------

(1 row)
``` works fine. If you double quote PG_NOTIFY to be "PG_NOTIFY" it will fail. and there is no reason to do "PG_NOTIFY". Do I understand right the issue?

Comment: He means that this will not work: `LISTEN Virtual; SELECT pg_notify('Virtual', 'payload');` with is correct. But he doesn't know how object identifiers work in pg and that this will work: `LISTEN "Virtual"; SELECT pg_notify('Virtual', 'payload');`

Comment: @VaoTsun The reason that I am testing `pg_notify('FOO', ...` is that `pg_notify(concat(NEW.region, ...` isn't working and NEW.region is in capitals.

Comment: @chrisdew - sorry - I would never decode that from your post :) Lukasz - thank you!

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński `listen 'Virtual'` fails with: `
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: syntax error at or near "'Virtual'"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/chris/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:572:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/chris/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:396:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/chris/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:132:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)`

Comment: @chrisdew `listen 'Virtual'` is very much different from `listen "Virtual"` - first is liesten to a string, the other is listen to identifier, If you would not have case mixed, could be without quotes

Comment: @chrisdew youn you pass 'Virtual' to `pg_notify` function, you pass a string, so it is in single quotes. when you run `NOTIFY "Virtual"` you use virtaul as channel name - an identifier

Comment: @VaoTsun You've found the issue, changing my code from `client.query("LISTEN 'Virtual'");` to `client.query('LISTEN "Virtual"');`fixes it all.  Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: try ` select pid,'pid',"pid" from pg_stat_activity limit 1;` to see how it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

confusion comes from quotes.
single quotes are used for a string, double are used for identifier and can be skipped to none if you don't use mixed case/start from number/ or other tricks.

when you run `pg_notify` function you pass 'foo' as a string argument and thus use single quotes, when you run `NOTIFY "Virtual"` you use `Virtual` as channel name - an identifier, so you need to use `"` here.

So as you answered yourself, changing

```
client.query("LISTEN 'Virtual'");
```

to

```
client.query('LISTEN "Virtual"');
```

fixes an issue

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Thanks for your help, you might guess that I'm new to Postgresql, after using MySQL for a long time.

Comment: sure - my pleasure. I adore Postgres

Answer (score 3):

You should look for an identifier definition: [Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Unquoted identifiers are case insensitive in that sense that regardless of how they are written by a user, Postgres sees them as in lowercase. In the function `pg_notify()` the first argument is **not** an identifier but a text literal which is treated as an identifier without parsing, so it is not converted to lowercase.